# Change properties from another field

Tags: yii2

I need you to change the **PRODUCT** field (dropdownlist) is changed the MIN and MAX properties **kartik\SLIDER** component

---- form ----

```
<?=
        $form->field($model, 'product_id', [
            'inputOptions' => [
                'class' => 'selectpicker '
            ]
        ]
        )->dropDownList(app\models\Product::getHierarchy(), ['prompt' => 'Selecione', 'class'=>'form-control required']);
?>

use kartik\slider\Slider;
echo $form->field($model, 'commission_percent')->widget(Slider::classname(), [
            'name'=>'commission_percent',
            'value'=>7,
            'sliderColor'=>Slider::TYPE_GREY,
            'handleColor'=>Slider::TYPE_SUCCESS,
            'pluginOptions'=>[
                'handle'=>'round',
                'tooltip'=>'always',
                'min'=>10,
                'max'=>50,
                'step'=>1,
            ]
        ]);
```

---- rules ----

```
['commission_percent', 'number','min'=>30,'max'=>40, 'when' => function($model) {
                return $model->product_id == 14;
            }],
```

**EDITED**

Each product has a max value and minimum commission amount. I do not know how to catch these values and transfer to the properties max and min of SLIDER.

**EDITED 2**

My controller actionListx return:

Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
Response content must not be an array.

My _form:

```
<?php
$productId = Html::getInputId($model, 'product_id');
$comissionId = Html::getInputId($model, 'commission_percent');
$url = \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('/dailyproductivity/listx');
$js = <<<JS
$('#{$productId}').on('change', function () {
    var form = $('#dailyproductivity-form');
    $.ajax({
        url: '{$url}',
        type: 'post',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            var min = data.min;
            var max = data.max;

            $("#{$comissionId}").data('slider').options.min = min;
            $("#{$comissionId}").data('slider').options.max = max;
            $("#{$comissionId}").slider('setValue', min);
        }
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
?>
```

My ProductivityController:

```
public function actionListx()
    {
        $model = new Dailyproductivity();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            $product = Product::findOne($model->product_id);

            if ($product !== null) {
                return [
                    'min' => $product->min_value,
                    'max' => $product->max_value,
                ];
            }
        }

        return [
        'min' => '0',
        'max' => '100'
    ];
}
```

Print

[image]

Comment: what is the problem?.

Comment: Hi @RumesShyaman  I do not know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not saving this min and max values and the correspond ids somewhere in your db (and i think you should), you can do that with pure js. Here is a example:

```
<?php
$productId = Html::getInputId($model, 'product_id');
$comissionId = Html::getInputId($model, 'commission_percent');
$js = <<<JS
$('#{$productId}').on('change', function () {
    var id = $(this).val();

    if (id == 14) {
        var min = 30;
        var max = 40;
    } else {
        var min = 0;
        var max = 100;
    }

    $("#{$comissionId}").data('slider').options.min = min;
    $("#{$comissionId}").data('slider').options.max = max;
    $("#{$comissionId}").slider('setValue', min);
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

And make sure to add the new rule in your model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // the other rules
        // ...
        ['commission_percent', 'number','min'=>0,'max'=>100] // the general values
        ['commission_percent', 'validate']
    ];
}

/**
 * @param string $attribute
 */
public function validate($attribute)
{
    if ($this->product_id == 14) {
        $min = 30;
        $max = 40;

        if ($this->attribute < $min || $this->attribute > $max) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'error message'));
        }
    }
}
```

But if you have a lot of products and each one have a specific value of min and max, instead of creating a bunch of `if statements`, you can create a new action that checks the model that have this two values (min and max) saved and return them. And you can access it  with a `ajax` call.

Here is a example of this ajax (assuming you added the `min_value` and `max_value` attributes in your `Product` model:

in your **view**:

```
$productId = Html::getInputId($model, 'product_id');
$comissionId = Html::getInputId($model, 'commission_percent');
$url = Url::to(['controller/action-with-ajax']);

$js = <<<JS
$('#{$productId}').on('change', function () {
    var form = $('#my-form-id');
    $.ajax({
        url: '{$url}',
        type: 'post',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            var min = data.min;
            var max = data.max;

            $("#{$comissionId}").data('slider').options.min = min;
            $("#{$comissionId}").data('slider').options.max = max;
            $("#{$comissionId}").slider('setValue', min);
        }
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

And your **controller**:

```
public function actionWithAjax()
{
    $model = new Model(); // the model you are using in this form

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        if ($product = Product::findOne($model->product_id)) !== null) {
            return [
                'min' => $product->min_value,
                'max' => $product->max_value,
            ];
        }
    }

    return [
        'min' => '0',
        'max' => '100'
    ];
}
```

Comment: cool.  I found it interesting your idea.
For each product_id I would have a MAX and MIN column?

Comment: Yes, i would recommend you do that. Maybe add those two extra columns in your product table. So, both in your `js` and your `rules`, instead of doing a `if statement`, you will check this value and give it to `max` and `min` variables.

Comment: In your `js`, is just a matter of replace the `if` by an `ajax` call, there is a lot of examples on how to do that here in stackoverflow. And the action you are calling will try to find this product, and return it or just return those two values. Same thing in your rules, try to find the product, and get the two attributes.

Comment: Let me know if you find any problem trying to apply it. :)

Comment: Can show me how do I get the MIN and MAX values via ajax and assign these values to the variable MIN and MAX Slider component?

Comment: Updated with an example.